# Simplest way to sum two dimensions? (Python)

Tags: python, list, int, sum, dimension

I need assistance on summing two dimensions.

Let's say I have [[0,1,2],[3,4,5]] as my dimensions, summing those numbers up would return int 15.

```
   def sum_dimensions(x):
       x = []
       answer = sum(x)
       return int(x)
```

Pointing out my mistake(s) in the code is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Let's get a bit into this. I used the following data set on my machine:

```
data = list(list(range(100000)) for i in range(1000))
```

I have the following results:

```
In [13]: %%timeit                                             
sum(sum(ele) for ele in data)
   ....: 
1 loops, best of 3: 1.15 s per loop

In [14]: %%timeit                                             
sum([sum([item for item in ele]) for ele in data])
   ....: 
1 loops, best of 3: 3.78 s per loop


In [15]: %%timeit                                             
sum(j for i in data for j in i)
   ....: 
1 loops, best of 3: 4.92 s per loop

In [16]: %%timeit                                             
sum(itertools.chain.from_iterable(data))
   ....: 
1 loops, best of 3: 1.61 s per loop

In [18]: %%timeit
sum(map(sum, data))
   ....: 
1 loops, best of 3: 1.16 s per loop
```

However for the small data set the `itertools` variant was 2 times faster than the `sum(sum` variant. `sum(map(sum` seems to map exactly to the `sum(sum(ele) for ele in data)` construct

Comment: Is this now about premature optimization?

Comment: heh, i though the sum of a generator expression would be more efficient than that. Good to know!

Comment: @Hyperboreus No. But the task is quite trivial and allows for multiple solutions of the same code complexity. Thus it is worth looking into how they compare, isn't it? It's for example interesting to see how bad the `j for i in data for j in i` construct performs, I didn't expect this.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

```
data = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5]]
sum([sum([item for item in ele]) for ele in data])
15
```

As pointed out by @filmor, this can be simplified as:

```
data = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5]]
sum([sum(ele) for ele in data])
15
```

As for as your code is concerned, if you are passing `[[0,1,2],[3,4,5]]` as `x` to the function:

```
answer = sum(x)
```

would throw a `TypeError`. The following

```
return int(x)
```

does not make sense either. The way to make your code work would be:

```
def sum_dimensions(x):
   answer = sum(x)
   return answer

data = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5]]
total_sum = 0
for sub_list in data:
    total_sum += sum_dimensions(sub_list)
```

Comment: `sum([item for item in ele])` can be written as `sum(ele)`.

Comment: or `sum(j for i in data for j in i)`

Comment: That is even better, yes :)

Comment: That would use up extra resources on big arrays. You should look for ways to replace Python loops with calls to `math` and `itertools` when performance can be a question.

Comment: What exactly? M4rtini's solution?

Comment: Yes. List comprehension is faster than `for` loop, but `sum` is still faster.

Comment: Routinely, and with 8Gb arrays. Makes you feel every extra cpu command inside the loop.

Comment: Another variant: `from itertools import chain; sum(chain.from_iterable(data))`

Answer (score 0):

It's Python, not C.

```
ar = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5]]
result = sum ( [sum(block) for block in ar] )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing other linear algebra, it might be worth considering `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array( [[0,1,2],[3,4,5]] )
print np.sum(x)
```

Comment: I prefer not using Numpy. Forgot to mention!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
>>>sum([sum(i) for i in [[0,1,2],[3,4,5]]])
```

Output:

```
15
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
>>> l = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5]]
>>> 
>>> sum(a for v in l for a in v)
15
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) also:

```
a = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5]]
sum(map(sum, a)) #15
```